# configure failed because of See `config.log' for more details

Tags: gcc, g++, tcl

I am trying to compile Tcl, but I got the following error:

```
~/apps/tcl8.6.6/unix> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local/Tcl
checking whether to use symlinks for manpages... no
checking whether to compress the manpages... no
checking whether to add a package name suffix for the manpages... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

`config.log`:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by tcl configure 8.6, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.59.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/home/michallorenc/.local/Tcl

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = flashlite1.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Tue Feb 9 22:46:17 UTC 2016

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
hostinfo               = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /sw/RCC/GCC/4.9.2/bin
PATH: /gpfs1/homes/michallorenc/.linuxbrew/sbin
PATH: /gpfs1/homes/michallorenc/.linuxbrew/bin
PATH: /gpfs1/homes/michallorenc/.linuxbrew/bin
PATH: /home/michallorenc/.linuxbrew/bin
PATH: /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
PATH: /opt/torque-rcc/default/bin
PATH: /opt/torque-rcc/default/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /opt/bio/ncbi/bin
PATH: /opt/bio/mpiblast/bin
PATH: /opt/bio/EMBOSS/bin
PATH: /opt/bio/clustalw/bin
PATH: /opt/bio/tcoffee/bin
PATH: /opt/bio/hmmer/bin
PATH: /opt/bio/phylip/exe
PATH: /opt/bio/mrbayes
PATH: /opt/bio/fasta
PATH: /opt/bio/glimmer/bin
PATH: /opt/bio/glimmer/scripts
PATH: /opt/bio/gromacs/bin
PATH: /opt/bio/gmap/bin
PATH: /opt/bio/tigr/bin
PATH: /opt/bio/autodocksuite/bin
PATH: /opt/bio/wgs/bin
PATH: /opt/ganglia/bin
PATH: /opt/ganglia/sbin
PATH: /usr/java/latest/bin
PATH: /opt/maui-rcc/bin
PATH: /opt/rocks/bin
PATH: /opt/rocks/sbin
PATH: /opt/sdsc/bin
PATH: /opt/sdsc/sbin
PATH: /home/michallorenc/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1385: checking whether to use symlinks for manpages
configure:1394: result: no
configure:1397: checking whether to compress the manpages
configure:1412: result: no
configure:1426: checking whether to add a package name suffix for the manpages
configure:1439: result: no
configure:1501: checking for gcc
configure:1517: found /sw/RCC/GCC/4.9.2/bin/gcc
configure:1527: result: gcc
configure:1771: checking for C compiler version
configure:1774: gcc --version </dev/null >&5
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:1777: $? = 0
configure:1779: gcc -v </dev/null >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/gpfs1/sw1/RCC/GCC/4.9.2/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-lto --enable-checking=release --disable-multilib --enable-shared=yes --enable-static=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-gold=default --enable-plugins --enable-ld --with-plugin-ld=ld.gold --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/gpfs1/sw/GCC/4.9.2 --with-local-prefix=/gpfs1/sw/GCC/4.9.2
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) 
configure:1782: $? = 0
configure:1784: gcc -V </dev/null >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:1787: $? = 1
configure:1810: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:1813: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
gcc: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program as)
0x409edc execute
    ../../gcc/gcc.c:2854
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
configure:1816: $? = 4
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "tcl"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "tcl"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "8.6"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "tcl 8.6"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:1855: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
BUILD_DLTEST=''
CC='gcc'
CC_SEARCH_FLAGS=''
CFG_TCL_SHARED_LIB_SUFFIX=''
CFG_TCL_UNSHARED_LIB_SUFFIX=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGS_DEBUG=''
CFLAGS_DEFAULT=''
CFLAGS_OPTIMIZE=''
CFLAGS_WARNING=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DLL_INSTALL_DIR=''
DLTEST_LD=''
DLTEST_SUFFIX=''
DL_LIBS=''
DL_OBJS=''
DTRACE=''
DTRACE_HDR=''
DTRACE_OBJ=''
DTRACE_SRC=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXTRA_APP_CC_SWITCHES=''
EXTRA_BUILD_HTML='@:'
EXTRA_CC_SWITCHES=''
EXTRA_INSTALL=''
EXTRA_INSTALL_BINARIES='@:'
EXTRA_TCLSH_LIBS=''
HTML_DIR=''
INSTALL_LIB=''
INSTALL_STUB_LIB=''
INSTALL_TZDATA=''
LDAIX_SRC=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAGS_DEBUG=''
LDFLAGS_DEFAULT=''
LDFLAGS_OPTIMIZE=''
LD_LIBRARY_PATH_VAR=''
LD_SEARCH_FLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
MAKEFILE_SHELL=''
MAKE_LIB=''
MAKE_STUB_LIB=''
MAN_FLAGS=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_DIR=''
PACKAGE_NAME='tcl'
PACKAGE_STRING='tcl 8.6'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='tcl'
PACKAGE_VERSION='8.6'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CFG_ARGS=''--prefix=/home/michallorenc/.local/Tcl' '
PLAT_OBJS=''
PLAT_SRCS=''
PRIVATE_INCLUDE_DIR=''
RANLIB=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SHLIB_CFLAGS=''
SHLIB_LD=''
SHLIB_LD_LIBS=''
SHLIB_SUFFIX=''
STLIB_LD=''
TCLSH_PROG=''
TCL_BUILD_LIB_SPEC=''
TCL_BUILD_STUB_LIB_PATH=''
TCL_BUILD_STUB_LIB_SPEC=''
TCL_HAS_LONGLONG=''
TCL_INCLUDE_SPEC=''
TCL_LIBRARY=''
TCL_LIBS=''
TCL_LIB_FILE=''
TCL_LIB_FLAG=''
TCL_LIB_SPEC=''
TCL_LIB_VERSIONS_OK=''
TCL_MAJOR_VERSION='8'
TCL_MINOR_VERSION='6'
TCL_MODULE_PATH=''
TCL_PACKAGE_PATH=''
TCL_PATCH_LEVEL='.6'
TCL_SHARED_BUILD=''
TCL_SHARED_LIB_SUFFIX=''
TCL_SHLIB_LD_EXTRAS=''
TCL_SRC_DIR='/home/michallorenc/apps/tcl8.6.6'
TCL_STUB_LIB_FILE=''
TCL_STUB_LIB_FLAG=''
TCL_STUB_LIB_PATH=''
TCL_STUB_LIB_SPEC=''
TCL_THREADS=''
TCL_UNSHARED_LIB_SUFFIX=''
TCL_VERSION='8.6'
TCL_YEAR=''
TK_SHLIB_LD_EXTRAS=''
ZLIB_INCLUDE=''
ZLIB_OBJS=''
ZLIB_SRCS=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_RANLIB=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build_alias=''
datadir='${prefix}/share'
exec_prefix='/home/michallorenc/.local/Tcl'
host_alias=''
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${prefix}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${prefix}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
prefix='/home/michallorenc/.local/Tcl'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_NAME "tcl"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "tcl 8.6"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "tcl"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "8.6"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: "gcc: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program as)" is ominous... Can you compile anything else? I wouldn't expect `as` to fail on such a simple piece of code, there's probably something else wrong with your system (corrupt `binutils`, or a library mis-match, or bad RAM...).